# Completely Delete JSON-Object from JSON-Array

Tags: php, json, object, unset

If i unset some Obkects in a JSON-Array via PHP, then i get an undefined Field with two empty []. But i want to delete the whole Object without [].

This is the  Code I am using:

```
// Unset Data Object from JSON-File
unset($data['server'][$Server][$ID]['id']);
unset($data['server'][$Server][$ID]['svc']);
```

JSON-File before "unset":

```
{
  "server": {
    "SERVER-01": [
        {"svc":"SVC1", "id":1},
        {"svc":"SVC2", "id":2},
        {"svc":"SVC3", "id":3},
        {"svc":"SVC4", "id":4},
        {"svc":"SVC5", "id":5}
    ],
    "SERVER-02": [
        {"svc":"SVC1", "id":1},
        {"svc":"SVC2", "id":2},
        {"svc":"SVC3", "id":3},
        {"svc":"SVC4", "id":4},
        {"svc":"SVC5", "id":5}
    ]
  }
}
```

JSON-File after "unset":

```
{
  "server": {
    "SERVER-01": [
        [],
        {"svc":"SVC2", "id":2},
        {"svc":"SVC3", "id":3},
        {"svc":"SVC4", "id":4},
        {"svc":"SVC5", "id":5}
    ],
    "SERVER-02": [
        {"svc":"SVC1", "id":1},
        {"svc":"SVC2", "id":2},
        [],
        {"svc":"SVC4", "id":4},
        {"svc":"SVC5", "id":5}
    ]
  }
}
```

EDIT:
The following Output i get with unset($data['server'][$Server][$ID]:

```
{
  "server": {
    "SERVER-01": {
        "1": {"svc":"SVC2", "id":2},
        "2": {"svc":"SVC3", "id":3},
        "3": {"svc":"SVC4", "id":4},
        "4": {"svc":"SVC5", "id":5}
    },
    "SERVER-02": [
        {"svc":"SVC1", "id":1},
        {"svc":"SVC2", "id":2},
        {"svc":"SVC3", "id":3},
        {"svc":"SVC4", "id":4},
        {"svc":"SVC5", "id":5}
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: `unset($data['server'][$Server][$ID])`…!?

Comment: what is `$Server` and `$ID`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing this:

```
// Unset Data Object from JSON-File
unset($data['server'][$Server][$ID]['id']);
unset($data['server'][$Server][$ID]['svc']);
```

Just stop at the ID, like this:

```
// Unset Data Object from JSON-File
unset($data['server'][$Server][$ID];
```

Now when you `json_encode` your array, you'll see it 's completely gone :-)

Comment: If i do this, then i get a complete different JSON-File -> see edited Question

Comment: I had to add the new data to a new array and then reencode this array:   $var=array();
 foreach($data['server'][$Server] as $key => $item) {
  
  $var['server'][$Server][] = $item;  
   
 }  echo json_encode($var, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT|JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK), "\n\n\n";

Comment: Glad you got there! Have a great day :-)